# Building clean Go application in Docker

Tags: docker, go, build

I'm trying to create Go web server into small Docker images. Ideally the clean image contains only the Go application itself (and maybe supporting web components, but not the Go-building environment).

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# golang:latest as build-env
FROM golang:latest AS build-env

RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN cd /app && GO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o myapp .
# go build -o myapp

FROM scratch
COPY --from=build-env /app/myapp /app/images /

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT /myapp
```

It uses the Docker Builder Pattern and scratch image, which is a special docker image that's empty.

It builds OK, but when I run it, I'm getting:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

**UPDATE:**

So the `ENTRYPOINT` need to be changed to the exec form:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/myapp"]
```

Having done that, I'm getting a new error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

Having use a small footprint Linux image as the base (i.e. Alpine Linux) instead of scratch wouldn't help either:

```
$ docker run -it -p 8080:8080 go-web-docker-small            
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

$ docker run -it -p 8080:8080 go-web-docker-small /bin/sh -i 
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

How to fix it? Thx!

Comment: @A.R, I have no problem running  `docker`. The problem is to get the clean image contains only the Go application itself without the Go-building environment. With it, I have no problem running  docker, whose last command is `CMD ["go", "run", "main.go"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While building Dockerfile provided by you, I am getting following error:

> COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cc1f8144192760ce7bf9cda7a7dfd0af16065901594c38609c813ea103cfd8d7/merged/app/images: no such file or directory

Fixed copy command and few others and image is building with following in Dockerfile

```
# golang:latest as build-env
FROM golang:latest AS build-env

RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN cd /app && GO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o myapp .
# go build -o myapp

FROM scratch
COPY --from=build-env /app/myapp .

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["./myapp"]
```

Comment: RE: _"and image is building"_. I have no problem building it (creating an `images` folder and you should build fine too) It is when I run it I go the problem. Are you able to run it?

Comment: Yes. I am able to run. However, I am wondering how the build command is working for you when `/app/images` directory itself does not exist. If it is building for you, just replace `ENTRYPOINT /myapp` to `ENTRYPOINT [./myapp]` in your Dockerfile and try once.

Comment: Thanks  Mayank, there is still something wrong with [my code](https://gist.github.com/suntong/bae094f0911a7d6d2d571283c8c9f648) after the fix -- I always get the "standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"" error no matter what. I've been trying all kinds of ways, and still no clue where the error comes from, Would you be so kind to post your code somewhere so that I can try it out please?

Comment: I am just using "hello world" program @xpt

Comment: OK, I'll accept yours as the answer and ask the follow up question separately. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 10):

The last line of your Dockerfile is

```
ENTRYPOINT /myapp
```

There are two forms of the ENTRYPOINT (and CMD and RUN) instructions.  An ["exec form"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) looks like a JSON list, and provides an uninterpreted list of arguments to run as the main container process.  A ["shell form"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) does not look like a JSON list, and is implicitly wrapped in `/bin/sh -c '...'`.

Your ENTRYPOINT uses the shell form, and a `FROM scratch` image doesn't have a shell, producing the error you get.  You can change this to the exec form

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/myapp"]
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that making the base image `FROM scratch` also impairs some capabilities from the vanilla Go code (at least out of the box), such as resolving SSL or other functions that depends on the underlying OS (as is the absence of the /bin/sh). That's why we usually use a small footprint Linux image as the base (i.e. Alpine Linux) instead of scratch.

Comment: Thank you David for solving my 1st question, and @GustavoKawamoto for answering my next question that I haven't asked -- because once I passed my 1st Q, I always get the "`standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`" error no matter what. I've been trying all kinds of ways, and still no clue where the error comes from, until I check here (was about to ask for help again). I believe the key is the *missing underlying OS*. In such case, Gustavo, please give formal answer, as *"clean image contains only the Go application itself"* is the wrong goal.

Comment: Hmm... *"clean image contains only the Go application itself" is the wrong goal*, hold on, there is still something wrong with [my code](https://gist.github.com/suntong/bae094f0911a7d6d2d571283c8c9f648). OP updated.